# Angularjs clock with no seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

I'm using this way to create a clock in my webpage

```
function TimeCtrl($interval) {
     var timeController = this;

     timeController.clock = { time: "", interval: 1000 };

     $interval(function () { 
         timeController.clock.time = Date.now();}, 
         timeController.clock.interval);
}
```

html

```
<span>{{ clock.time | date:'medium'}}</span>
```

It's cool, it works well but I don't need seconds. I would keep this `medium` date filter but without seconds. Is it possible?

note: I use angular translate so I have to be able to change the format of the date

Comment: You can specify any [date format you want](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date#overview). `'medium'` is equivalent to `'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'`, so try: `date:'MMM d, y h:mm a'`

Comment: the good thing of the "medium" filter is that it adapts if I change language with angular translate. With you way It doesn't do this

Comment: I'm not that familiar with angular translate module. See if [this example](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/860) will help: `<span translate="translateKey" translate-values="{date: (clock.time | date:'MMM d, y h:mm a')}"></span>`

Comment: Also in this way you can't see the different changing language. the best thing is the bipin answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know more about language change but you can do that with using two different date filter like this

```
<span>{{ clock.time | date:'mediumDate'}}</span><span>{{ clock.time | date:'shortTime'}}</span>
```